# Does the English language have a word explaining a song in your head that you can't stop singing?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions, synonyms

Sometimes after listening to a popular song you can't stop repeating it in your head. Is there any term for this in English? You can't say the same in Russian using one word.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about our site.

Comment: Doesn't actually have to be a popular song. or FTM even a song in the sense that it has words.  Same thing happens to me with bits of classical music...

Comment: FYI: [How are musical hooks defined/studied in psychology?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20000/12937)

Answer (score 105):

You can use "[Earworm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earworm)" which means:

> a song or melody that keeps repeating in one's mind

Comment: Was just about to say this, haha. I've never heard the word used before, it's more common to say "I have a song stuck in my head" in my experience. If someone told me they had an earworm I'd ask them to see a doctor. But hey, the word exists anyway

Comment: I think it's a new coining. I've only started hearing it over the past year or two. MW has an article on it - https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/earworm-meaning-origin

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've been hearing the term for a few years now, but it's not in what I'd call "general" use, even today. It seems to have been adopted by "in groups" connected with SF/Fantasy fandom.

Comment: Earworm is widespread well outside groups connected with SF or fantasy fandom. I think I might have to explain it to my grandmother, or someone who has been in a coma for some years, and has just regained consciousness, but most ordinary people here in the UK would know what it means. The earliest known usage is in Desmond Bagley's 1978 novel Flyaway.

Comment: I agree with Michael that it’s not all that new or rare. [DJ Earworm](http://djearworm.com/UnitedStateOfPop.php) has been doing the mashups he’s famous for since 2007, and I was familiar with the term for years before that...

Comment: I more commonly hear (and use) the related term **brainworm** (Pacific Northwest Mountain states area of USA). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm

Comment: Western US native English speaker: I've never heard the term "Earworm" or "Brainworm" before, learned something new today, thanks! I would just say a song is "stuck in my head" like Kamil's answer.

Comment: Native US English speaker here. I find "earworm" is more used when talking about the phenomenon or when mentioning such a song with the explicit intent to get it stuck in someone's head (e.g. "hey, here's an earworm for you" along with a Rick Astley youtube link) whereas "stuck in [your/my] head" is more often used for talking about the feeling of actually being in that state.

Comment: This is the one. I've found more musically-inclined people (here in the USA at least) are much more likely to know it. Particularly musicians.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've been hearing "earworm" for at least 10 years, possibly 20.

Comment: Unfortunately, "corn earworm" is a common agricultural pest in the US, and hence effective web searching for the origin of the musical sense is difficult at best.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm): An earworm, sometimes known as a brainworm,[1] sticky music, stuck song syndrome,[2] or Involuntary Musical Imagery (INMI)[3] is a catchy piece of music that continually repeats through a person's mind after it is no longer playing.[4] Phrases used to describe an earworm include "musical imagery repetition", "involuntary musical imagery", and "stuck song syndrome".[1][5][6] The word earworm is possibly a calque from the German Ohrwurm.[7] The earliest known usage is in Desmond Bagley's 1978 novel Flyaway.[8]

Comment: As an Eastern US native English speaker, I've heard and have used the term for years.

Comment: @HotLicks It is definitely derived from the German "Ohrwurm", which means exactly the thing OP describes. It can often be found in lists like "10 German single words that have no direct English translation".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: _"most ordinary people here in the UK would know what it means_" Disagree

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit - At coffee time just now, I asked eight people I work with, and six said they knew what it meant. One said "Is it a catchy tune or lyric?" and one had never heard of it. All of my family, nine people aged 14 to 70, have heard of it. Not scientific, I know, but still.

Comment: _Earworm_ is a commonplace word in the Berenstein bears universe.

Comment: I am a southern US native speaker who is a musician and is around a lot of musicians. I have never heard "earworm" or "brainworm" before.

Comment: Similar to @R..'s comment, I would make the subtle distinction that an earworm is a tune *very likely* or even *intentionally crafted* to get stuck in your head. Songs that are not earworms may also get stuck in your head.

Comment: Earworm/brainworm is much more handy than "stuck in my head" when saying something like "yeah, thanks for the earworm" (sarcastically) after your friend plays you their favorite song, which happens to be annoyingly catchy.

Comment: I remember reading about earworms in a book on memetics at least five years ago, and it was an older book when I started reading it.  Google [N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earworm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearworm%3B%2Cc0) shows that it started becoming popular in 1920, and peaked in 1940.

Comment: @CortAmmon: Here's another [Google N-gram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earworm%2Ccorn+earworm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearworm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccorn%20earworm%3B%2Cc0) that adds the bigram "corn earworm" to your "earworm" search. The two lines correlate so strongly that it's quite save to assume that most, if not all tokens of "earworm" in Google N-gram refer to the bugs, and not to the tunes.

Comment: In my family we said "I've got it on the brain".

Answer (score 52):

You could say the song is "stuck in your head". I haven't found a dictionary listing the phrase, but here's a [Time article](http://time.com/5115013/song-stuck-in-head-earworm/) on the subject, with the title "Why Do Songs Get Stuck In Your Head?"

For example usage, to express "after listening to a popular song you can't stop repeating it in your head" I would say:

> I heard [popular song] on the radio, and now it's stuck in my head.

"Earworm" is a very related term. Essentially, if a song gets stuck in peoples' heads frequently then it can be called an earworm. On the other hand, the phrase "stuck in your head" is how you talk about a specific time when it happened, such as "it's stuck in my head right now" or "it was stuck in my head when I left yesterday".

Comment: FWIW, as a native English speaker in the US, I have never heard the term "Earworm", I would just say the song is stuck in my head.

Answer (score 12):

The [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohrwurm) on **"Ohrwurm"** lists earworm as a loanword from German. To be more precise, it is a [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) (thanks @PLL), a word for word translation of the two parts Ohr and Wurm (ear and worm).

It also has other suggestions: sticky music, head music and the [English Wikipedia on loanwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_German_expressions_in_English#Music) calls it catchy tune.

Based on the comments by two native speakers and their up votes - those suggestions are even less used. Catchy tune is better used for an appealing and memorable tune rather than a song which is stuck in your head at the moment.

Comment: As an American native speaker, I don't think I've ever used the terms "sticky music" or "head music" used in this way. A "catchy tune" is a tune which is appealing and memorable; it's not the right phrase to use for a tune which is stuck in your head *at that moment*.

Comment: @TannerSwett As a British native speaker, I agree with everything in your comment.

Comment: @TannerSwett thank you for that addition. I've integrated your remarks into my answer. German English tends to introduce new words which native speakers never heard or use it in a completely different way - that's why I was cautious.

Comment: I’ve also never heard of _sticky music_; it rather sounds like a song about molasses. Odd term.

Comment: Just to elaborate on a detail: *earworm* is not precisely a loanword, but rather a **calque** of *Ohrwurm*.  A loanword would be something like *zeitgeist*, where the German word itself gets used in English; a [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) is when a word or phrase gets translated component-by-component, like *Ohrwurm* becoming *earworm*.  (Just to keep things fun, *calque* itself is a loanword from French, whereas *loanword* is a calque of the German *Lehnwort*.)

Comment: @PLL thank you for that, I'm really not a language person - learning much more from my post than anyone else I guess.

Comment: Remember that being a native speaker doesn't mean that you're the ultimate judge of what goes in a language. The newspaper that is given as a reference for "sticky music" and "head music" in the Wikipedia article cites [a blog post](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/the-science-of-earworms-or-why-you-cant-get-that-damn-song-out-of-your-head/) fron Scientific American. This post does list "brain worms", "sticky music", "cognitive itch", and "stuck songs" as other expressions refering to the phenomenon, alongside the "earworm". This has nothing to do with "German English".

Answer (score 1):

Another term I've hear used is "**song virus**".  Surprisingly to me, I couldn't find this listed anywhere other than [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=song%20virus), but it's definitely a usage I've heard as an American native speaker.

Comment: As another American, I can't recall ever hearing that term used before.  Maybe it's a regional term?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I polled a couple people that I know and they recognized it.  I guess it could be regional.  The term also connotes the song being spreadable from person to person, not just being stuck in your own head.

Comment: I've never heard this myself, but if I heard it (and had a little bit of context), it would be pretty understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[hook](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hook)**:

> Catchy part of a song that draws in the listener, not necessarily the
>   chorus.

Comment: Thanks for contributing - just a few pointers to help improve this answer. Urban dictionary tends to be a less reputable source for definitions, as anybody can add to it and many are jokes - where possible, I'd recommend something like Oxford English or Merriam Webster. Oxford English contains the definition for "hook" that you're describing. I'd also tend to make it clear what the word is, its definition and why you feel it's most appropriate - rather than leaving it to the link (which may become unavailable in future). (OE hook (2.1): https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hook)

Comment: That is a word, but it doesn't really have anything to do with what's asked here - it's something that describes a part of the structure of a song, it doesn't have anything to do with the state of the listener.

Answer (score 1):

The word I've heard is "[earbug](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Earbug)".

Here's the example there:

> Person 1: Why are you acting so weird?
>
> Person 2: Sorry, I have an earbug. I can't get this stupid Metallica
>   song out of my head.